# WebScarab, HTTPS and github

Tags: security, web, github, https, webscarab

Ok this is weird, I'm using WebScarab to analyse some HTTPS traffic.
Every time I trie to access an HTTPS website, I'm asked to add an security exception (which is ok and works).
The problem is, when I trie to access https://github.com there is no way to add an exception for it. So I just can't surf over github.com using WebScarab as proxy.

And idea why this is happening?

**UPDATE**:

I tried again using Firefox (29.0.1 just updated) on OS X (10.9.2) using webscarab (1.0 (1.0) master version) and it now works (I don't know maybe I did something wrong).
Anyway, I still have a problem with Kali Linux and Iceweasel (22.0) using webscarab (again master version). This is what I see[image]

Comment: Have you tried clearing the cache or the known/trusted certificate store of your browser?

Comment: Tried. Also using an anonymous tab. I tried on OS X using chrome, firefox and safari (with safari it somehow works) and on Kali Linux using iceweasel. Only on github.com I'm not able to add a certificate exception.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this warning message since Webscarab using the self signed certificate to connect the https website.
In latest version of browser FF or IE , browser restricts the option to skip for self signed certificate. 
**Solution:**
You can try in lower version of FF or IE.